# Accessing an application in XPages with Lotus connections using the same authentication

Tags: authentication, lotus-notes, xpages

I'm trying to access an e-mail by lotus connections through a link to the iNotes, but when I click on the link is redirected to the login page of iNotes and does not take the same authentication at the lotus connections. How do I prevent this? There is also a solution if, instead I use iNotes, I use an XPages application that requires authentication?

Comment: Declan gave solution for this. I too have seen this issue.

Answer (score 5):

This is a server administration issue.

You will need to make sure that you have Single SignOn setup across both the Domino server and the IBM Connections server. Once the LTPA keys have been exported from IBM Connections and then imported into Domino and both server are in the same domain then authentication is automatic.

When the user is logged into Connections and clicks a link that brings them to the Domino server the LTPA SSO will kick in and automatically authenticate them and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Declan writes he is some information if you want to use SSO between server side XPages code and IBM Connections: http://www.openntf.org/blogs/openntf.nsf/d6plinks/NHEF-8TY9EV